# Start and end of events assign to month of start based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a data for 2000 events with start and end date of each event and the length.
What I am trying to do is finding the frequency of events by month and year. But several of events are split between two consecutive months (say May and June) and want for these events to be reported to the month over which they stay longer. But if an event split equally between tow month then it will be reported to the month of start.

Eg:

```
> date01[1:5,9:11]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  StrD       EndD       EvLength  
  <date>     <date>     <drtn>  
1 1993-12-30 1994-01-01  3 days # this would be reported Dec frequency 
2 2000-07-23 2000-08-02 11 days # this would be reported July frequency 
3 2001-02-28 2001-03-01  2 days # this would be reported Feb  frequency (as it started in Feb)
4 2006-05-29 2006-06-01  4 days # this would be reported May frequency (as it started in May)
5 2010-07-30 2010-08-04  6 days
```

I tried to use `group_by` (from `dplyr`), but still not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

1. dates to date format with `ymd()` from `lubridate` package.
2. `mutate` days in previous and next Month with `days_in_month` function and basic arichmetic. Note the start day is count therefore `+1` to start date.
3. get the `month` depending on which month has more days with an `ifelse`
4. get the abbreviation of Months with `month.abb[Month]`
5. get the `Year` from start date.
6. group and summarise

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(1:2, ymd)) %>% 
    mutate(prev_month_days = days_in_month(StrD)-day(StrD)+1,
           next_month_days = day(EndD)) %>% 
    mutate(Month = ifelse(prev_month_days>= next_month_days, month(StrD), month(EndD))) %>% 
    mutate(Month = month.abb[Month]) %>% 
    mutate(Year = year(StrD)) %>% 
    group_by(Year, Month) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
```

Output:

```
   Year Month     n
  <int> <chr> <int>
1  1993 Dec       1
2  2000 Jul       1
3  2001 Feb       1
4  2006 May       1
5  2010 Aug       1
```

Comment: I have upvoted, one last thing please, I have added "Duration0= max(EvLength)" at the end of the code after "n= n()". That just to get the max length base on the same conations. But I got "NA". Is it possible to do so. I would really appreciate your time and assistant.

Comment: You can "ignore" not-defined/not-available elements when using max by setting na.rm=TRUE, i.e. `max(EvLength, na.rm=TRUE)`. This is done deliberately, so that you have to decide what to do with "imperfect" data (for example clean it beforehand, etc.).

Comment: @aorali: Sorry I missed your comment. At the end it s no good idea, because here the column `EvLength` is not accessable. You could replace: `summarise(n = n())` by `summarise(n = n(), Duration0=max(EvLength))`